# How to call another method from another class with Popup?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using [Rg.Plugins.Popup plugin](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup):

The popup is to select users to assigned to a New Task page. When I select a user from the `ListView`, it supposed to call another method in the `NewTask` page to display the selected user.

What I am having trouble with is that when I try to call another method from the `NewTask` class, it's not doing anything and I will appreciate your help! I need to call a method in the `NewTask` class from the `SearchUsers` class to pass over data. I also tried using the `MessagingCenter` and it's still doesn't display the data from the `SearchUsers` class to the `NewTask` class.

#### SearchUsers.xaml

```xml
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="20, 0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Frame Padding="0" BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout Padding="10, 0, 10, 10">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="Search Existing Users" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Button Text="Close" Clicked="ClosePopup" HorizontalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <ScrollView x:Name="usersScrollView">
                    <ListView x:Name="usersList" ItemSelected="usersList_ItemSelected">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
```

#### SearchUsers.xaml.cs

```cs
    public partial class SearchUsers : PopupPage
    {
        ...

        void usersList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = e.SelectedItem as Users;

            NewTask newT = new NewTask();
            newT.SelectedUser(selectedItem);
            PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);

            //DisplayAlert("HI", selectedItem.Email, "DONE");

            //NewTask.SelectedUser(selectedItem);

            //MessagingCenter.Send(new Users() { Id = selectedItem.Id, Name = selectedItem.Name, Email = selectedItem.Email }, "PopUpData");
        }
    }
```

#### NewTask.xaml.cs

```cs
     public partial class NewTask : ContentPage
    {
        public NewTask()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SelectedUser(Users u)
        {
            SelectedUserView.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, true);
            SelectedUserName.Text = u.Name;
            SelectedUserEmail.Text = u.Email;

            //DisplayAlert("HI", u.Name + " : " + u.Email, "DONE");

            //MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Users>(this, "PopUpData", (value) =>
            //{
            //    SelectedUserView.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, true);
            //    SelectedUserName.Text = value.Name;
            //    SelectedUserEmail.Text = value.Email;
            //});
        }
```

> NewTask.xaml

```
<ContentPage Title="Add New Task" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TaskApp.Task.NewTask">
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Create" Order="Primary" Clicked="AddTask"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<StackLayout>
    <TableView Intent="Form" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Search Existing Users">
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="13, 5">
                            <Button Image="search.png" Text="Select a User" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="SearchUsers"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Padding="13, 5" x:Name="SelectedUserView" IsVisible="false">
                            <Label x:Name="SelectedUserName" />
                            <Label x:Name="SelectedUserEmail" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
            ...
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: `usersList_ItemSelected` is creating a **new instance** of `NewTask`, it is **not** using the instance that already exists.  `MessagingCenter` is a good way to pass messages between classes.  There are great examples in the docs

Comment: @Jason As I mentioned above, I tried using the MessagingCenter, but it's still not passing over data. Can you please see my above commented codes for the MessagingCenter and see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you need to call Subscribe in the constructor

Comment: I would use event handler instead of MessagingCenter and yes its not using existing `NewTask` which seems to be expected. Is Popuppage is called after NewTask and you are trying to return and display selected values?

Comment: @Morse Can you please provide an example code? I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Morse I just added my xaml code for NewTask.xaml

Comment: [Check this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) basically you would want event in PopUp page and subscribe to it from NewTaskPage

Comment: Because the New Task page is not on the screen, the method will not be called. To display the popup, the application needs to navigate to the Task page first. `private void listView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var model = e.SelectedItem as _Model;

    Navigation.PushAsync(new TaskPage());

    MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "Hi");
}`.